# moving an object within a set area in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, object

Hi there I have an object that I can move on touch but I need it to only be able to move with in a set area so from :

x 0 to 320 and 
y 0 to 200

`player.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];`

any ideas?

this is so that if the user trys to move it out of this area it just hangs on the outer edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code here is actually pretty simple, you just want to detect whether it has exceeded the boundaries, and if it has, the correct it. Assuming `player.center` is something like an `NSPoint`, the code could be something like:

```
if(player.center.x <= 0){
    player.center.x = 0;
}else if(player.center.x >= 200){
    player.center.x = 200;
}
if(player.center.y <= 0){
    player.center.y = 0;
}else if(player.center.y >= 300){
    player.center.y = 300;
}
```

If you want the edges to not pass the sides, then you could just do something like:

```
if(player.center.x - player.xSize / 2 <= 0){
    player.center.x = 0 + player.xSize / 2;
}
```

And the same for the other x bound and the y bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MIN and MAX to constrain a value.

```
CGFloat minX = 0.0f;
CGFloat maxX = 320.0f;
CGFloat minY = 0.0f;
CGFloat maxY = 200.0f

CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(MIN(minX, MAX(maxX, location.x)),
                             MIN(minY, MAX(maxY, location.y)));
player.center = center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
CGRect validRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0);
CGPoint touchPoint = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
if(CGRectContainsPoint(validRect, touchPoint) {
    player.center = touchPoint;
}
```